# Solving double integrals of combing min and max functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to solve a double definite integral if it looks like as follows,

$\displaystyle \int_a^b\int_c^d \max(\min(A,e^x-e^y)-B,0)\,dx\,dy,$ where $A$ and $B$ are constant. Thank you in advance.

Regards
Ray

Comment: where is the $B$?